# How to insert into every other 10th element in a flutter list index?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, element, listviewitem

Currently I have a list builder of search terms.  I've successfully inserted a custom container at every 10th element by using

```
if (index % 10 != 0 || index == 0) {
   return Container(
      child: Text[index]}
   else {
      return Container(
                child: "Custom Image")}
```

What's happening is that index number is not changing and the 10th Text element is being overridden by my "Custom Image".

Any ideas on how to get this done by expanding the index by 1 and making my Custom Image the 11th element displayed.  I'm doing this twice in my code with a Future ListView.Builder and a StreamBuilder.

Comment: The reason is that when it is 10th item, it will insert Image, then, index++, it move to 11th item and build the 11th Text, your 10th item will miss. My suggestion is use `if (index % 10 != 0 || index == 0) {return Container(child: Text[index]);}else {return Column(children: [ Container(child: Text[index]),Container(child: "Custom Image");}` You may need to adjust the Size and Alignment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the container with `Text` widget at every 10 index, and container with `CustomImage` otherwise, then your condition is wrong. It should be `(index+1) % 10`

Tried this code using https://dartpad.dev/flutter?

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (context, index){
 
    if ((index+1) % 10 == 0 || index == 0) {
       return Container(child: Text('$index 10'));
  
  }
    else{
          return Container(child: Text('$index Image'));
    }
  }
    )
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So simple like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 35,
  itemBuilder: (_, i) => Container(child: Text((i+1) % 10 != 0 ? i.toString() : 'Image')),
)
```